# How to Read Json data in Restful web services using jax-rs

Tags: java, web-services, restful-architecture

How to pass json as input to restful web services and how to insert the json data in to database.

Comment: That really is a broad question and no research work shown

Answer (score 0):

Usually you pass JSON payload sending request with POST or PUT method and setting Content-Type header to application/json. Then on the server it converts to an object representation with help of library, for example Jackson.

```
POST /rest/sms/templates HTTP/1.1
Host: your-host.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "template": "Hello, ${userName}"
}
```

Comment: thanks for response bu i want server side in restful web service